# How to change start point when finding Maclaurin series of $xln(1+x)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the Maclaurin series for $f(x) =x\ln(1+x^3)$.

Unfortunately notes (and it seems online) are very inconsistent about whether the equality to memorize is $\ln(1+x)=\sum^{\infty}_{1} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n=1}$, or $=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$, or $=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (-1)^{n}\frac{x^n}{n}$. Does the +/- matter in the first two? Are any of these correct/wrong?

Knowing that, I also have trouble subbing in the leading x. My answer key shows:
$$
\ln(1+x^3)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(x^3)^n}{n}
$$
Which seems fine (assuming the first of my three assumed formulas are correct.But when it comes time to bring in the x, I don't know why the start point changes:
$$
x \ln(1+x^3)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{x^{3n+1}}{n}
$$
Why can't I just multiply the x in? Won't the denominator be zero on the first term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula is $\ln(1+x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ for $|x| < 1$. Therefore $$x \ln(1+x^3) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{n}$$ for $|x|<1$. There is no reason to change the starting point in the sum.

If you want to remember the expression of $\ln(1+x)$ just remember that for $|x|<1$, $$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} x^n$$ hence $$\frac{1}{1+x} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (-1)^n x^n$$

Now, because $(\ln(1+x))'=\frac{1}{1+x}$, you can integrate the serie of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ to find the one of $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask a side question? I really don't trust the answer sheet now. We have $e^{(t-1)^2} = \sum_{n=0} \frac{(t-1)^{2n}}{n!}$, but I don't understand after we get $\sum_{n=0} \frac{(t-1)^{2n}}{n!} = 1+ \sum_{n=1} \frac{(t-1)^{2n}}{n!}$ (I assume because we just know the first term is 1), how we can say $1-e^{...} = -\sum_{n=1} \frac{(t-1)^{2n}}{n!}$? If you told me 1-e^(...) was negative the sum starting from 0 I'd be fine, but i don't see why the 1+ before the "absorb's" the subtraction like 1-(1+sum)?

Comment: I don't understand your question, it seems like words are missing.

Comment: So eqn #1 (from the comment) is just an 'application' of the Taylor series for $e^x$ right? Then we are told by shifting the start point to n=1 we can extract a 1 to get $1+\sum [...]$ where [...] is the fraction but that's not the focus. Our actual question was not to find $e^x$ but instead $1-e^x$ hence I'm trying to understand if $e^x = 1+\sum [...]$ , why isn't $1-e^x = 1-(1+\sum [...])$ and hence just the sum starting at 1? According to the answer key it's negative the sum starting at 1.

Comment: Wait I answered my own question it seems I forgot about the bracketing ahhh